# Can't remove of add class from HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three coloured buttons. When I pick a button, I want it to be selected, and the other two to be deselected. red, blue and yellow are objects with the property isSelected set to true or false. I can select one button once, setting isSelected to true for that button. However, I can't seem to select a new button and deselect the current one.

(I know I can do this with jQuery easily... but I'm trying to learn how to use Javascript objects here...)

The code below doesn't run, it's the bits I think are relevant to the problem without the HTML and CSS. The app is on CodePen: http://codepen.io/isachenx/pen/LxEOOR

My idea is to set isSelected to true or false for each of the selectors. If isSelected is true, I add the class .selected to the html string, if it's false, the string does not include the class. I then re-render (at least that's what I think I'm doing) the string every time the li element is clicked...

```js
    //create constructor
    function Selector(colour){
      this.colour = colour
      this.isSelected = false
    }

    //set method to select and deselect the list items
    Selector.prototype.selectColour = function(){
      this.isSelected = true
    }

    Selector.prototype.deselectColour = function(){
      this.isSelected = false
    }

    //render the string for the list item to HTML 
    Selector.prototype.toHTML = function(){
      let htmlString = ""
      htmlString += '<li id="' + this.colour + '" class="' + this.colour
      if (this.isSelected){
        htmlString += ' selected'
      }
      htmlString += '"></li>'
      return htmlString
    }
    
    //Constructor to render every list item to html
    function Controls(){
      this.selectors = []
    }

    Controls.prototype.add = function(selector){
      this.selectors.push(selector)
    }

    Controls.prototype.renderInElement = function(list){
      list.innerHTML = ''
      for (let i=0; i<this.selectors.length; i++){
        list.innerHTML += this.selectors[i].toHTML()
      }
    }

    let controls = new Controls

    let red = new Selector('red')
    let blue = new Selector('blue')
    let yellow = new Selector('yellow')

    controls.add(red)
    controls.add(blue)
    controls.add(yellow)

    let controlElement = document.getElementById('controlButtons')
    controls.renderInElement(controlElement)

    let redButton = document.getElementById('red')
    redButton.onclick = function(){
      red.selectColour()
      blue.deselectColour()
      yellow.deselectColour()
      controls.renderInElement(controlElement)
    }

    let blueButton = document.getElementById('blue')
    blueButton.onclick = function(){
      blue.selectColour()
      red.deselectColour()
      yellow.deselectColour()
      controls.renderInElement(controlElement)
    }

    let yellowButton = document.getElementById('yellow')
    yellowButton.onclick = function(){
      yellow.selectColour()
      red.deselectColour()
      blue.deselectColour()
      controls.renderInElement(controlElement)
    }
```

Comment: You have not provided enough code, for instance: what is controls.renderInElement?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've added everything now...

Comment: Codepen is working fine for me.

Comment: Oops, my mistake - that linked to the version I did in jQuery. I've updated the link. The non-working JS only version: http://codepen.io/isachenx/pen/LxEOOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your code, a second click on either button does not work.
The reason is that `onclick` is set only for the first time.

Your `toHTML` function clears the existing buttons (line 33: `list.innerHTML = ''`), as a result clears their `onclick` events. You have to set them again inside `toHTML`.

Like so:

```
Selector.prototype.toHTML = function(){

  // set the on click function to the desired color
  let onclickStr = 'setOnClick(\'' + this.colour + '\')';

  let htmlString = ""
  htmlString += '<li id="' + this.colour + '" class="' + this.colour
  if (this.isSelected){
    htmlString += ' selected'
  }

  // Note the following change
  htmlString += '" onclick="' + onclickStr + '"></li>'
  return htmlString
}
```

Then, wrap your `xxxbutton.onclick` functions with:

```
function setOnClick(color) {
  let redButton = document.getElementById('red')
  let blueButton = document.getElementById('blue')
  let yellowButton = document.getElementById('yellow')
  if(color==='red'){    
    red.selectColour()
    blue.deselectColour()
    yellow.deselectColour()
  }else if(color==='blue'){
    blue.selectColour()
    red.deselectColour()
    yellow.deselectColour()
  }else{
    yellow.selectColour()
    red.deselectColour()
    blue.deselectColour()
  }
  controls.renderInElement(controlElement)
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/92n57ws6/)

Comment: I don't get the last bit. How do I wrap the functions? Sorry that you'll have to spell it out... but I'm lost. I'll try again tomorrow, totally fried atm... thanks for the answer...

Comment: @IsabellaChen Edited. See attached jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Setting `isSelected` to `true` or `false` doesn't change the class on the DOM element.  To add/remove a class:

```
var colourObj = document.querySelector(colour);
colourObj.classList.add('selected');
//or to remove a class
colourObj.classList.remove('selected');
```